dotnet7 in Noble?
I'm looking for dotnet7 or dotnet-sdk-7.0 in my (just installed, release build of) 24.04 repositories, so far apt-get tells me "Unable to locate package..."
How can I get dotnet7 in Noble?
Thanks,

Noble has dotnet8. Does that not work for you?

Possibly, going to take a while to verify if it does or not.
